# adb shell ls giving strange results

Tags: adb, shell, nook-simple-touch

Environment:
running adb in command window on Windows XP PC
running adbKonnect on Nook Simple Touch (rooted; running Android 2.1)

When I type

```
adb shell ls \sys
```

I get a list of the folders there.

When I type

```
adb shell ls \sys\module
```

I get an error that there is no such file or directory, even though it is listed in the first step. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `adb shell ls -l /sys` and check the output. Most likely, access to the `/sys/module` directory has limited access.

It doesn't matter that your device is rooted, when you're not using your root powers. To view the contents of "restircted directories":

```
# open a shell
adb shell
# obtain root permission
su -
# now access your target
ls -l /sys/module
```

When issuing the `su -`, you will have to approve a popup to confirm superuser access − at least on the first try. You then can tell your superuser/superSU app to remember your choice.